# SSIS performance in this case scenario

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssis

Can this kind of logic can be implemented in SSIS and is it possible to do it in near-real time?

Users are submitting tables with hundreds of thousands of records and waiting for the results for up to 1 hour with the current implementation when the starting table have about 500.000 rows (after the STEP1 and STEP2 we have millions of records). In the future the amount of data and the user base may drastically grow.

### STEP 1

We have a table (A) of around 500.000 rows with the following main columns: `ID, AMOUNT`
We also have a table (B) with the prop.steps and the following main columns: `ID_A, ID_B, COEF`

**TABLE A:**

```
id  amount
a   1000
b   2000
```

**TABLE B:**

```
id_a,id_b,coef
a,a1,2
a1,b2,2
b,b1,5
```

We are creating new records from all the 500.000 records that we have in the table A multiplying the `AMOUNT` by the `COEF`:

**OUTPUT TABLE:**

```
id, amount
a,1000
a1,2000
a2,4000
b,2000
b1,10000
```

### STEP 2

Following custom logic, we are assigning the amount of all the records calculated before to some other items with the following logic:

**TABLE A**

```
ID,AMOUNT
a,1000
a1,2000
a2,4000
b,2000
b1,10000
```

**TABLE B**

```
ID,WC,COEF
a,wc1,0.1
a,wc2,1
a,wc3,0.1
a1,wc4,1
a2,wc5,1
b,wc1,1
b1,wc1,1
b1,wc2,1
```

**OUTPUT TABLE:**

```
ID,WC,AMOUNT
a,wc1,100
a,wc2,1000
a,wc3,100
a1,wc4,2000
a2,wc5,4000
b,wc1,2000
b1,wc1,10000
b1,wc2,10000
```

The other steps are just joins and arithmetical operations on the tables and the overall number of records can't be reduced (the tables have also other fields with metadata).

Comment: What is the current implementation?  There may be reasons why it is so slow that don't require a change to SSIS.

Comment: Good question @iamdave, I don't have that insight yet.

Comment: You're saying you don't know what the current implementation is at all?  Is it SQL based/custom programme/etc?

Comment: Exactly, I don't know. I was asked about the possibility of implementing this using SSIS and not given any details about the existing process, technologically speaking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my personal experience that kind of logic can be completely implemented in SSIS.

I would do it in a Script Task or Component for two reasons:

- First, if I understood correctly, you need an asynchronous task to
  output more data than your input. Scripts can handle multiple and diferent outputs.
- Second, in the script you can implement    all those calculations
  which in the case of using other components would take a lot    of them and
  relationships between them. And the most important    aspect, the
  algorithm complexity is kept in relation with your    algorithmic
  design which can be a huge boost on performance and scalability if
  you get a good complexity, two aspects that, if I get    it right again,
  are fundamental.

There are, though, some professionals that have a bad opinion of "complex" scripts and...

The down step of this approach is that you need some ability with .NET and programming, also most of your package logic will be focus there and script debugging can be more complex than other components. But once you get to use the .NET features of SSIS, there is no turning back.

Usually getting near real time in SSIS is tricky for big data sets, and sometimes you need to integrate other tools (e.g. StreamInsight) to achieve it.